# Password protect a cname subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection, cname, setenv

I'm trying to build and test a "m." subdomain for a website I'm working on. "m.domain.com" is simply a cname for "domain.com" and will be used to set a server-side boolean so the mobile version of the site will serve exactly the same pages, just with different css and scripts.

While I'm testing, I want to require a password for all requests made to m.domain.com. I've tried several .htaccess variants on environment variable solutions, and this is what I have right now:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host m\.domain\.com is_mobile

AuthType basic
AuthName "Mobile site"
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"
Require valid-user

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=is_mobile
Satisfy any
```

With this code, "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" display normally. "m.domain.com" prompts for a password as expected. However, once it's entered, the server returns a 500 error on any request.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out that a little inversion and reordering did the trick.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^(www\.)domain\.com$ not_mobile

AuthType basic
AuthName "Mobile site"
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=not_mobile
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

I'm still curious to know why the other configuration created the 500 error, though, especially since it only occurred for the subdomain I wanted password protected.