# Password protecting by match

Tags: .htaccess, authorization

I want to protect certain files I'm still working on from unprotected access, so I guessed, I just use an identifier in their file-name like "_temp" and protect all url-matches for that by htaccess.

Using this with FileMatch for files is nice, but I also did already write a few htaccess-lines so the GET-site-parameter becomes a subdomain. And subdomains aren't files, so no FileMatch. Also I noticed, _ doesn't appear to be valid for a subdomain^^ so ".*temp.*" should be enough...

Then I used SetEnvIf, but it either doesn't protect anything or everything in all cases.
can you tell me what I did wrong?

```
SetEnvIf HOST .*temp.* notallowed
SetEnvIf Request_URI .*temp.* notallowed

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Under construction"
AuthUserFile /home/auth/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home/auth/.htgroup

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from env=notallowed
Require user qwerty
Allow from all
```

This should give me an password-prompt at huitemp.mysite.de , hui.mysite.de/huitemp.php and hui.mysite.de/?site=huitemp but not on hui.mysite.de.

PS, I also found this post:
[Password protect a cname subdomain with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615778/password-protect-a-cname-subdomain-with-htaccess)
But it is kind of the opposite I want to do and the top-example doesn't really work for me (as the author already said).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deny from all first, then allow from !notallowed:

```
SetEnvIf HOST .*temp.* notallowed=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI .*temp.* notallowed=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Under construction"
AuthUserFile /home/auth/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home/auth/.htgroup

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require user qwerty
Allow from env=!notallowed
```

Comment: well, this blocks all sites, regardless containing temp or not. Does it matter whether there are some RewriteCond and RewriteRules at the end of the .htaccess?

Comment: @Julian it doesn't matter if you have rules unless the rules are changing the URI to "temp" or some other type of access control (like using the `F` flag).

Comment: Well they are changing the site. I'm redirecting the subdomain to become a parameter of index.php and change the display, so this parameter always appears as subdomain. but I'm not using the F-Flag, ohne `L`, `R`, `NC` and `QSA`... Ah, I feel so dumb... of course I changed the site to "mysite", but the original name includes temp ^^ so, with _temp it may have worked, but as _ is not allowed... I used another phrase and now it works^^ thanks again!